# Delaying window.open() after a function

Tags: javascript, mysql, ajax

I have this insertData() function to save to DB and to show window.open() based on that entries to database
so this is my attempt,

```
function(isConfirm){
    if (isConfirm) {
        insertData();
        window.open("../../../html/reports/cashreceipt_print.php?sr_record="+sr_id);
    } else {
        swal("CANCELLED", "", "error");
    }
});

function insertData(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "../../../html/main/divpages/submit_data.php",
        data: sentReq,
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            if (response.indexOf("GAGAL") == -1) {
                window.location.href = "main.php";
            } else {
                alert("GAGAL INSERT");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

so the problem here when the new window open, sr_record= most of the time doesnt show in that popup. SR_RECORD will be inserted and window open will call the SR_ID that is just inserted in the insertData(). I could find any solution that works best in my case. Please help me

Comment: Put the `open` in the `success` function

Comment: FYI: pop up blockers will block the window from opening since a user action did not cause it to open.

Answer (score 1):

insertData is AJAX, the A stands for asynchronous, so it doesn't finish by the time you call window.open, use either the success function you have or use jquery's .done method:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  context: document.body
}).done(function(data) {
  // do your 'data' stuff here
});
```

---

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "../../../html/main/divpages/submit_data.php",
    data: sentReq,
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success: function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
       // your sr.id is hopefully on the response object( if its being sent back properly.
    }
});
```

Comment: success: function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    if (response.indexOf("GAGAL") == -1) {
                        window.location.href = "main.php";
                    } else {
                        alert("GAGAL INSERT");
                    }
                }
            }).success(function(){
                window.open("../../../html/reports/cashreceipt_print.php?sr_record="+sr_id);
            });

i do like this but cant see the pop up working.

Comment: then you have some other issue going on can you log the response and see sr_id?

Answer (score 0):

ok the solution is this simple, i open the popup first then sent back to main.php

```
function insertData(){
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "../../../html/main/divpages/submit_data.php",
                data: sentReq,
                dataType: 'JSON',
                success: function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    if (response.indexOf("GAGAL") == -1) {
                        window.open("../../../html/reports/cashreceipt_print.php?sr_record="+sr_id);
                        window.location.href = "main.php";
                    } else {
                        alert("GAGAL INSERT");
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```